# CC.Net is not opening on web browser

Tags: continuous-integration, server, port, cruisecontrol.net

I am new to CC.Net ,

I am new to cc.net , I have installed cc.net and tried to open it on web browser But could not to open it.

It is working fine with console.

My 80 port is taken by XAMPP (which is off for now). Still I tried accessing via localhost:21234 but again unable to open it.

Comment: Port 21234 is reserved for the ccnet .net remoting api and as such won't work as you might expect in a browser

Comment: Is the ccnet site/application started in iis? It may have been stopped by iis due to a port conflict with XAMPP when ccnet was installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, Simon Laing is right I am using IIS and the problem was I didn't start the world wide web publishing services (services.msc / www service).

It was not conflicting with my XAMPP 80 because , It was already turned off.